# What's the cleanest way to emit a signal when QString is changed? (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, qstring

I have a global QString object, and I would like to tie any changes to it to emit a Signal that I could connect to in other parts of my code.

I see that the [QString Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#details) doesn't have signals, so how would I go about doing this?

I'm using PyQt, but either a general Qt or a specific PyQt answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you wrap access to the QString in a singleton derived from QObject. Give the singleton a setter for the strings updated value, and emit a signal from the singleton if it has changed.